# Azure Powershell command cannot find my VM under my resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to change the TCP Port timeout on my Ubuntu VM in Azure, and am following [this guide](https://emamonline.smartertrack.com/kb/a122/to-increase-windows-azure-tcp-port-timeout-to-30-minutes.aspx) to do so, however I seem to get stuck at Step 8 where I have to type the following command:

`Get-AzureRmVM -Name "digitron" -ResourceGroup "DIGITRON-RG" |
 Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress`

Where it spits back the following error:

> Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress : The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/digitron' under resource group
>   'DIGITRON-RG' was not found.
>   StatusCode: 404
>   ReasonPhrase: Not Found
>   OperationID : '5031da35-262c-4e1a-a85b-885a6a0fd36c'
>   At line:1 char:63
>   + ...  "digitron" -ResourceGroup "DIGITRON-RG" | Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress
>   +                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress], NetworkCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.GetAzurePublicIpAddressCommand

What's strange here is if I run the command Get-AzureRmVm, the powershell will spit back:

> ResourceGroupName     Name Location          VmSize                OsType         NIC ProvisioningState
>   DIGITRON-RG                 digitron   eastus Standard_DS2_v2  Linux digitron727         Succeeded

Now reading the error makes me think that the VM itself has no public IP address, but I've set it in the Azure Portal as seen in this image (where it says 40.71.98.172 etc):

[image: in this image]

Why is the Powershell giving me this error?

Comment: FYI in the future, probably best to block out your subscription id.

Comment: That's a good point, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/digitron' under
>   resource group 'DIGITRON-RG' was not found.

Because `Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress` can't get the right parameter, this error means the resource can't find in DIGITRON-RG. For test, we can use Get-AzureRmResource to test the resource exist or not:

```
PS > Get-AzureRmResource |  ?{$_.name = "digitron"}
```

By the way, the command [Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.network/v2.1.0/get-azurermpublicipaddress) need parameters: **-Name** (the name of the public IP address), **-ResourceGroupName** (the name of the resource group)

```
PS > Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name "jason-ip" -ResourceGroupName "jason"


Name                     : jason-ip
ResourceGroupName        : jason
Location                 : eastus
Id                       : /subscriptions/5xxxxabb-222b-49c3-9488-0361e29a7b15/resourceGroups/jason/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/jason-ip
Etag                     : W/"5a7200b2-7c2b-4c7a-be27-0bbb7c8f4665"
ResourceGuid             : 32xxxf-750a-46a4-abda-c25xxx2b64
ProvisioningState        : Succeeded
Tags                     :
PublicIpAllocationMethod : Dynamic
IpAddress                : 13.92.255.103
PublicIpAddressVersion   : IPv4
IdleTimeoutInMinutes     : 30
IpConfiguration          : {
                             "Id": "/subscriptions/5xxxxb-222b-49c3-9xx8-0361e29a7b15/resourceGroups/jason/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/jason647/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1"
                           }
DnsSettings              : null
```

We can use this command to get the public IP direct, and increase the timrout to 30 minutes.

Comment: I think I managed to figure it out - your test command returned nothing (strangely enough) but I ran `Get-AzureRmResource` and it listed a bunch of information, all containing "digitron" in the name - I found the appropriate listing for the public IP address and went through the remaining steps to change the idle timeout time and it took! I'll go ahead and mark this as the correct answer.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script I used to get the Private and Public IP for an Azure ARM VM:

```
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "MyResourceGroup01"
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name "MyVM01"
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $(Split-Path -Leaf $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id)
$nic | Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | Select-Object Name,PrivateIpAddress,@{'label'='PublicIpAddress';Expression={Set-Variable -name pip -scope Global -value $(Split-Path -leaf $_.PublicIpAddress.Id);$pip}}
(Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $pip).IpAddress

#Output:    
Name      PrivateIpAddress PublicIpAddress
----      ---------------- ---------------
ipconfig1 10.0.0.10        MyVM01-pip

40.80.217.1
```